# Is it possible to run multiple instances of one selenium test at once?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have done some research and the consensus appears to state that this is impossible without a lot of knowledge and work. However:

- Would it be possible to run the same test in different tabs simultaneously?

If so, how would I go about that? I'm using python and attempting to run 3-5 of the same test at once.

This is not a generic test, hence I do not care if it interrupts a clean testing environment.

Comment: Have you looked at setting up several virtual machines to run the tests simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, look up `multiprocessing`, it will take **knowledge and work**, unless you are looking to hire someone to do the job for you, then it just takes *money*.

Comment: Do you need them to be in different tabs? or different windows is ok as well? I presume you don't really need them to be diffferent tabs but multiple browsers sessions on your box? Do you need to do this yourself or you have a budget?

Comment: @AliRad it could be multiple windows as well. I'd prefer to do it myself but could devote some money to it

Comment: Look at TestNG, you should be able to find frameworks that achieve this. Else look at https://butlerthing.io/products#demovideo. Drop us a message and will be happy to discuss this with you

Comment: look at [seleniumbase](https://seleniumbase.io/) or other comercial alternatives

Answer (score 15):

I think you can do that. But I feel the better or easier way to do that is using different windows. Having said that we can use either `multithreading` or `multiprocessing` or `subprocess` module to trigger the task in parallel (near parallel).

**Multithreading example**

Let me show you a simple example as to how to spawn multiple tests using `threading` module.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import threading
import time


def test_logic():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    url = 'https://www.google.co.in'
    driver.get(url)
    # Implement your test logic
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.quit()

N = 5   # Number of browsers to spawn
thread_list = list()

# Start test
for i in range(N):
    t = threading.Thread(name='Test {}'.format(i), target=test_logic)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    print(t.name + ' started!')
    thread_list.append(t)

# Wait for all threads to complete
for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()

print('Test completed!')
```

Here I am spawning 5 browsers to run test cases at one time. Instead of implementing the test logic I have put sleep time of 2 seconds for the purpose of demonstration. The code will fire up 5 firefox browsers (tested with python 2.7), open google and wait for 2 seconds before quitting.

Logs:

```
Test 0 started!
Test 1 started!
Test 2 started!
Test 3 started!
Test 4 started!
Test completed!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 3):

*Python 3.2+*

#### Threads with their own webdriver instances *(different windows)*

Threads can solve your problem with a **good performance boost** ([some explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68997963/1207193)) ***on different windows***. Also threads are lighter than processes.

- You should use a [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) with each thread using its own webdriver.
- Also consider adding the `headless` option for your webdriver.

The example bellow uses a `chrome-webdriver`. To exemplify uses integer as argument `url_test` for the test function `selenium_test` 6 times.

```
from concurrent import futures
from selenium import webdriver

def selenium_test(test_url):
    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless") # make it not visible
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)  
    print("testing url {:0} started".format(test_url))        
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")  # replace here by driver.get(test_url)
    #<actual work that needs to be done be selenium>      
    driver.quit()  

# default number of threads is optimized for cpu cores 
# but you can set with `max_workers` like `futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=...)`
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor: 
  future_test_results = [ executor.submit(selenium_test, i)  
        for i in range(6) ] # running same test 6 times, using test number as url
  for future_test_result in future_test_results: 
    try:        
        test_result = future_test_result.result() # can use `timeout` to wait max seconds for each thread               
        #... do something with the test_result
    except Exception as exc: # can give a exception in some thread, but 
        print('thread generated an exception: {:0}'.format(exc))
```

**Outputs**:

```
testing url 1 started
testing url 5 started
testing url 3 started
testing url 4 started
testing url 0 started
testing url 2 started
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at TestNG, you should be able to find frameworks that achieve this.

I did a brief check and here are a couple of links to get you started:

[Parallel Execution & Session Handling in Selenium](https://www.guru99.com/sessions-parallel-run-and-dependency-in-selenium.html)

[Parallel Execution using Selenium Webdriver and TestNG](https://www.ecanarys.com/Blogs/ArticleID/235/Parallel-Execution-using-Selenium-Webdriver-and-TestNG)

If you want a reliable, rebost framework that can do parallel execution as well as load testing at scale then look at TurboSelenium : https://butlerthing.io/products#demovideo. Drop us a message and will be happy to discuss this with you.